# Only process $_POST elements that begin with a certain string

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I am processing a form that will receive lots of elements through $_POST. A certain number of these (too large a number to write out manually) follows a pattern:

```
$_POST['city_1']
$_POST['city_2']
$_POST['city_3']
$_POST['city_4']
```

etc.

The way the form is set up, I'm not sure how many elements like this are going to be sent over — it could be one, it could be 50. How can I process just a few of the $_POST elements based on their names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a multidimensional array instead.

Your HTML form fields could look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="cities[city_1]">
<input type="text" name="cities[city_2]">
<input type="text" name="cities[city_3]">
<input type="text" name="cities[city_4]">
```

In your PHP code you can then loop through your cities by accessing `$_POST['cities']`:

```
foreach($_POST['cities'] as $city)
{
  echo $city;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$cities = preg_grep('/^city_\d+$/', array_keys($_POST));

foreach($cities as $city) {
    echo $_POST[$city];
}
```

Or

```
foreach($_POST as $name=>$value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'city_') !== 0) continue;

    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

´foreach` iterates through all the elements of an array. Then check if the requirements are met.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    if(preg_match("/^city_\d+$/", $key))
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
  $length = strlen($needle);
  return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}


foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
  if (startsWith($k, 'city_')
  {
    // Process parameter here ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through $_POST like an array.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
  //filter based on $key
}
```